# how can I make URL folder name to keep changing values

Tags: web

Here it is. I have a website for example

https://abcd.com/bfnmmjkujk/index.html

Is there anyway to make "bfnmmjkujk" to keep changing values randomly (eg to fd2xbfZna and so on) each time someone visits the website?

I am actually a noob at this so i haven't tried much fix on it. I am hosting on  Linux VPS, centos 6 64bit

Actually experienced it on some websites so i know its possible. Thank you

Comment: You'd just need something to *generate* that random link, and then configure your server to accept any random path as valid (see the duplicate), and then… do… something… with that.

Comment: i have gone through the duplicate file and I still cant get it. Quite confusing for me since im a noob.. Can you summarize what i can write in the .htaccess file to achieve this. Thanks

Comment: In your .htaccess file you'd need to write a rule that accepts any random path and rewrites it to some existing file, e.g. `RewriteRule .*/index.html index.html`. With this you can enter any URL like `/foobarbaz/index.html`, and you'll always get the same `index.html` file back. Beyond that… no idea what you want to do with that…